# Sacando el sentido de letra de canción del siglo XVII

Tags: discusión, preguntas, ámbito

Estoy preparando la canción "Un Sarao de la Chacona" (también conocida por el nombre "A la vida bona") de Juan Arañés (m. c. 1649) para mi conjunto de música antigua.  La letra contiene varias frases arcaicas que no entiendo, y quiero pedir ayuda para comprenderlas.

¿Sería esto asunto válido para una pregunta?

Comment: Preguntas similares: " [What does “Bolobonchi” mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10405/5481) - [¿Qué significado tiene “guantes” en esta canción de Silvio Rodríguez?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21600/5481) - [¿Qué significa “ese juguito e' parcha que te…”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21914/5481). Revisa otras preguntas con los tags [tag:poesía] y [tag:letras-de-canciones] para ver preguntas similares, cómo se han planteado y qué tipo de respuestas han recibido en base a cómo han planteado la pregunta (y a la propia canción)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como reglas básicas

- Pon una pregunta "por duda". Si hay varias frases que no entiendes pon una pregunta para cada una. Eso ayuda a tener preguntas concretas y mejores respuestas por pregunta.
- Las preguntas deben ser sobre el español. Viendo [la letra de la canción](https://www.musixmatch.com/es/letras/Juan-Ara%C3%B1%C3%A9s/Chacona-A-la-vida-bona) yo también veo muchas cosas que no entiendo, como

> Porque se casó Almadán, se hizo un bravo sarao, dançaron hijas de Anao con los nietos de Milán. Un suegro de Don Beltrán y una cuñada de Orfeo, començaron un guineo y acabólo una macona.

Si preguntases quién es el tal Almadán, Anao u Orfeo, evidentemente es off-topic. Si preguntas que es un *Sarao* o una *macona* puede ser on-topic. Recuerda que las preguntas también deben de mostrar un poco de esfuerzo previo, así que se cerraría como off-topic aquellas que pudiesen resolverse mirando en el diccionario.

Si preguntas por el uso de esas palabras con `Ç` (començaron, moça) Puede salir una pregunta interesante, ya que obviamente la cedilla no es una letra del alfabeto español.

En cualquier caso ten en cuenta que hemos de ser conscientes de que el autor de la canción se puede estar tomando licencias poéticas u obviando un poco el sentido de la narración en pro del ritmo, métrica, etc. Quizá no es que las frases sean "arcaicas", si no que carecen de sentido (en pro del ritmo, rima u otra cosa). Igual alguien puede sacar sentido de

> Salió la Raza y la traza todas tomadas de orín, [...] Entre la Raza y la traza se levantó tan gran lid

Yo personalmente pienso que el autor se deja llevar por la rima y que no hay que darle demasiadas vueltas. Todavía con más razón viendo

> Salió una carga de Aloe con todas sus sabandijas, luego, bendiendo [sic] alelixas, salió la grulla en un pie.

Pero lo mismo hay una acepción de alguno de esos términos que hace que todo tenga sentido y merezca la pena preguntar.

---

No se puede garantizar que no se van a cerrar sin verlas, pero en principio no deberían ser off-topic. O mejor dicho, se puede preguntar lo que quieres preguntar redactando buenas preguntas que se adhieren a [What topics can I ask about here?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Ante la duda, redacta tus preguntas, si hay un problema trataremos de ayudarte vía comentarios, le pediremos un poco de paciencia a esos usuarios de "gatillo fácil" con los votos negativos y si hay que cerrarlas o reabrirlas tampoco es el fin del mundo.

Comment: "...no es una letra del alfabeto español", mejor dicho, *ya* no lo es jaja.